# What is the meaning of number 1e5?

Tags: numbers, notation, exponentiation

I have seen in some codes that people define a variable and assign values like 1e-8 or 1e5.

for example

```
const int MAXN = 1e5 + 123;
```

What are these numbers? I couldn't find any thing on the web...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`1e5` is a number expressed using [**scientific notation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), specifically [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), and it means *1 multiplied by 10 to the 5th power* (the 'e' meaning 'exponent').

So `1e5` equals `1*100000` and is equal to `100000`. The three notations are interchangeable meaning the same.

Comment: For more on the scientific notation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: Just to note, for Python, `1e5` and `100000` are slightly different in that one's a `float` and one's an `int`. But they are equal.

Answer (score 31):

`1e5` means 1 × 10<sup>5</sup>.

Similarly, `12.34e-9` means 12.34 × 10<sup>−9</sup>.

Generally, `AeB` means A × 10<sup>B</sup>.

Comment: This! I think people who say 1e5 is equal to 10 to the 5th power are giving an incomplete answer. So I like your answer: `1x10^5`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

this is scientific notation for 10^5 = 100000

Answer (score 0):

1e5 is 100000. 5 stand for the amount of zeros you add in behind that number. For example, lets say I have 1e7. I would put 7 zeros behind 1 so it will become 10,000,000. But lets say that the number is 1.234e6. You would still add 6 zeros at the end of the number so it's 1.234000000, but since there is that decimal, you would have to move it to the right 6 times since it's e6.

Comment: `1.234e6` ->
`1234000`

Comment: this is the one definition I had in mind, but it was confusing some times. The accepted answer is better, more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The values like:
1e-8 or 1e5

means;

> `1e-8 = 1 * 10^(-8)`

And

> `1e5 = 1 * 10`