# What does "e" mean in logged output of a floating point number

Tags: floating-point, numbers, number-formatting

If I output a float or a double and it logs something like `-5.58794e-09`, then does this mean that the number is close to zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of number 1e5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174531/what-is-the-meaning-of-number-1e5)

Comment: Epsilon is a different concept than e (exponent)

Comment: "[E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)".

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of [scientific notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) called E Notation, where the 'e' means "powers of  10." In this style `-5.58794e-09` means `-0.00000000558794`; a decimal (one negative power of 10) and eight zeros (the other eight negative powers of 10) before the original digits.

Whether or not you consider this "close to zero" depends on what you are using it for.